# How to change legend title position when I have multiple scales created with ggnewscale package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, legend, ggnewscale

I created a plot which has 2 color scales and 2 linetype scales made with the `ggnewscale` package. I want the legend to appear at the bottom of the plot and the legend titles to appear above the labels. I did it halfway, because in my attempts, the first scales (from `geom_vline()`) don't appear the way I want. I even tried to indicate the desired position of this scale before declaring the next scales with `new_scale()` and `new_scale_color()`.Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

# Attempt 1

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = wt,
           y = mpg)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = gear,
                 color = "Important line",
                 linetype = "Important line")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Important lines",
                        values = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Important lines",
                     values = "red") +
  new_scale("linetype") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cyl,
                color = cyl)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(title.position = "top"),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))

# Attempt 2

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = wt,
           y = mpg)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = gear,
                 color = "Important line",
                 linetype = "Important line")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Important lines",
                        values = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Important lines",
                     values = "red") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                                 label.position = "bottom"), # Before new scales
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "top",
                              label.position = "bottom")) +
  new_scale("linetype") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cyl,
                color = cyl)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(title.position = "top"),
         color = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

Both attempts produce the same plot, which is not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure wether there is another option but what worked for me when making use of `ggnewscale` is to style the guide via the `guide` argument of the scale. To make this work I added a ´scale_color_discrete`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

ggplot(data = mtcars,
       aes(x = wt,
           y = mpg)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = gear,
                 color = "Important line",
                 linetype = "Important line")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Important lines",
                        values = 1, guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top") ) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Important lines",
                     values = "red", guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
  new_scale("linetype") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cyl,
                color = cyl)) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]